# Can I travel to US with the Italian carta d'identita?

Tags: usa, residency, nigerian-citizens, italian-residents

I'm a citizen of Nigeria but am living in Italy as an immigrant.

Recently I got the Italian carta d'identita (11 year residence permit).

Can I use this to travel to the US? How do I apply and what else is required?

Comment: The Italian residence permit might *help* to get an US visa, since you are less likely to be perceived as an illegal immigrant. You still have to get the visa.

Comment: Aren't Italian _residence permits_ usually known as "permesso di soggiorno"? "Carta d'identita" sounds more like an ID card than a permit.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I doubt you can get a permesso di soggiorno valid 10+ years. Even a carta d'identita' is only valid 10 years. However, in either case, none of them are going to get you into the USA

Comment: I'm assuming that he's had Italian residency for 11 years.

Answer (score 8):

No. Even Italians can't use a carta d'identita' to visit the US. You need a passport.

Comment: And since you are a citizen of Nigeria, you also need a visa.  Again, having Italian residency doesn't exempt you from this.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am pretty sure that even if you are an italian citizen the passport is not enough, and you need a visa anyhow

Comment: @Ant Ever heard about the Visa Waiver Program?

Comment: @fkraiem Oh, of course.. For some reason I thought it was about moving there.. Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 6):

The Italian *Carta d'Identita* for immigrants is different from the one they issue for the Italian citizens; on the cover of the carta d'identita for the immigrants/ foreigners it's written ***"Non valida per l’Espatrio"*** which in English means *'not valid for traveling abroad'* ***[image: here's a sample picture]***

The Italian citizens can use the *Carta d'Identita* within the EU travels, but traveling to the US they do need a passport as well!